# Convert Reverse Moving Average Formula to C#

Tags: c#, moving-average, trading, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance

I have been racking my brain trying to convert this formula to C# with no success.

[REMA Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaaGl.png).
[image]
I am decent in doing proggies but not in Math.

> Where 0 < λ ≤ 1 is a decay factor.
> When λ < 1, the exponentially weighted moving average assigns greater weights to the  prices.
>
> Contrary to the regular exponential moving average that gives greater
> weights to the most recent prices, the reverse exponential moving
> average assigns greater weights to the oldest prices and
> decreases the importance of the most recent prices.

Comment: Thanks for asking a question on stack overflow! In order for us to help you, you're going to have to post some of the code that you have tried and be more specific about some of the issues that you're having.

Answer (score 2):

### Efficient `REMA()`  <sup>with error-checking & context-specific return values</sup>

**Efficient?** Yes, avoids repeating duplicate expensive ops ( or relying on compiler optimisation tricks )

**With Error-checking?** Yes, almost a must for Q/A procedures.

**Context-specific?** Yes, returns **`{ -1. | REMA( k, lambda ) }`** which allows the caller to handle the corner case of input error(s).

```
double[] fTimeSeriesPRICE;     // a forward-stepping storage ( vs. a MT4 reversed-stepping model )

public double REMA( int k, double lambda )
{   
    if (  lambda <= 0.0        // lambda shall not fall on/under  0.0
       || lambda >  1.0        //        shall not grow beyond    1.0
       || k      <= 0          // depth  shall not be negative or 0
       )
       return -1.0;            // context-protecting RET value

    int aCurrentPricePTR  = fTimeSeriesPRICE.Length - 1;
    int aMaxIterableDEPTH = Math.Min( aCurrentPricePTR, k );

    double numerator   = 0.0;
    double denominator = 0.0;  // REMA formula-expansion contains +1 at the end, never less, never negative
    double lambdator   = 1.0;  // lambda ^ ( ( k - j ) == 0 ) == 1.0

    for ( int aReverseSteppingPTR  = 0;
              aReverseSteppingPTR <= aMaxIterableDEPTH;
              aReverseSteppingPTR++
              )
    {   numerator   += lambdator * fTimeSeriesPRICE[aCurrentPricePTR - aReverseSteppingPTR];
        denominator += lambdator;
        lambdator   *= lambda;
    }
    return numerator / denominator; // numerically fair, denominator never < +1.0
}
```

Comment: Thank you user. Essentially I want to convert this over to Ninja script (Ninja trader Platform) which is similar to MT4 when it comes to referencing the bars on the chart ([0] being the current bar). How would you code it with reversed stepping.

Comment: StackOverflow encourages users to keep Questions focused on a single, original topic. **Do not hesitate to [Accept] this answer** for the first, original question **and open a next, new question, as you indicated.**

Answer (score 1):

This appears to me to be one summation divided by another.  Here is my attempt at a straight-forward answer.  My results were definitely averages that were more heavily weighted toward the earlier entries in the list, but I don't claim to know if they were correct.

```
double[] m_prices;

public double Rema(int k, double lambda)
{
    // Simple parameter validation
    if(lambda == 0.0 || k == 0)
        return 0.0;

    // Ensure the iteration will not be larger than the number of entries
    int t = m_prices.Length - 1;
    k = Math.Min(t, k);

    double numerator = 0;
    double denominator = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= k; j++)
    {
        // Preform the 2 sigma operations from the formula
        numerator += Math.Pow(lambda, k-j) * m_prices[t - j];
        denominator += Math.Pow(lambda, k-j);
    }

    // Simple error check
    if (denominator == 0.0)
        return 0.0;
    return numerator / denominator;
}
```

Comment: proposed scheme will fail upon int k < 0 ( due to pointer algebra ) and upon lambda < 0 ( due to underflow the supremum given by the defined range ) and int j shall never fall under 0 ( due to pointer underflow limit of reversed access to m_prices[] for large k-s )

Comment: Define fail.  If k<0 then the for-loop will not run and it will hit the error-check at the bottom of the function.
From what I could tell from the formula, j should never go below 0 intentionally.